# Why all application logs are written to uwsgi log?

Tags: python, logging, uwsgi

I'm using dJango+uWSGI for a web project. But I found that all my logs will be written to the uwsgi log!!

The situation is that: When I write a log entry using logger.xxx, the logger I configured in settings.py will receive the log entry, but the uwsgi.log will also have a log written to that file! And the most strange things is that, in **some** of my projects, my application logs will be written to logs files as I configured, and all daemon process logs are written to uwsgi.log; but **the other** projects' application logs will ALSO be written to uwsgi.log!

Here is my logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
    },
    'detail': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(message)s'
    },
    'message_only': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
    'file':{
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'class':'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        'filename':  os.path.join(LOG_BASE, 'web.log'),
        'when': 'D',
        'backupCount' : 3
    },
    'pref':{
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'formatter': 'message_only',
        'filename': os.path.join(LOG_BASE, 'pref.log'),
        'maxBytes': 10 * 1024 * 1024, # 10MB
        'backupCount' : 5
    },
    'err':{
        'level':'ERROR',
        'class':'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'formatter': 'detail',
        'filename': os.path.join(LOG_BASE, 'err.log'),
        'when': 'D',
        'backupCount' : 3
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'myproject' : {
        'handlers': ['file', 'err' ],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'myproject+prefs' : {
        'handlers': ['pref'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    }
}
}
```

And my uwsgi.xml:

```
<uwsgi>
<socket>:8888</socket>
<env>DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings</env>
<module>django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()</module>
<processes>4</processes>
<master />
<master-as-root />
<!-- request timeout -->
<harakiri>15</harakiri>
<post-buffering>32768</post-buffering>
<daemonize>/var/log/myproject/uwsgi.log</daemonize>
<listen>32768</listen>
<socket-timeout>4</socket-timeout>
<disable-logging />
</uwsgi>
```

And here is how I use the logging:

```
import logging
from time import time

logger = logging.getLogger('myproject')


logger.info('my log')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just mix Django logging system and uWSGI.

```
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s | %(message)s'
    },
...
    },
'handlers': {
    'console':{
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple'
    },
...
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['console', ],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
        },
    },
```

this add logging all requests to console and this logs handle uWSGI.

`'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',` this is key for save log to uWSGI logs.

And you Django logs saves to `'filename': os.path.join(LOG_BASE, 'err.log'),`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the daemonize tag in uwsgi.xml

The documentation (http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc) say:

> Blockquote
>   Run the processes in background using a logfile or a udp server
>
> --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi.log
>
> will damonize uWSGI writing log messages to /var/log/uwsgi.log

Comment: But I think the /var/log/uwsgi.log should only contain daemon process logs, not my application logs.

Comment: What happen if you try to execute logger.info('blabla') in the python console?

Comment: I get nothing out for `logger.info('blabla')`.